# Covert to value to minutes in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi

How can I convert these values in Powewrbi to minutes, and the subtract from 43800(minutes in a month), divide by 43800 and put the result a new column, the seconds can be ignored:

This is how the value look in powerbi
Duration
2 hours 36 minutes 30 seconds
11 hours 19 minutes

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can try to do that with Powerquery. Powerquery is an excel option to change types and do agg functions. It is also supported by Power BI.

Comment: Is the starting value a date / time or the text "Duration 2 hours 36 minutes 30 seconds 11 hours 19 minutes"?

Comment: @DarylWenman-Bateson it's a text value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of Power Query, create a table or import your data
[image: Data source example]

Make sure your starting column is marked as Text.

Define a New Column with M called Hours

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Text Between Delimiters", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([TimeString], " ", " "), type text)
```

Define a new Minutes column

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Add Hours", "Minutes", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([TimeString], " ", " ", 2, 0), type text)
```

Now add a custom column formula to calculate your minutes in month.  I'm not 100% sure of your exact calculation, but this should get you very close

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Add Minutes", "Percentage of Minutes in month ", each (1-(43800 - (Number.FromText([Hours]) * 60) - Number.FromText([Minutes] )) / 43800)*100)
```

You should now have something like this

[image: M string to minutes in month]

In the Advanced Editor, the M code will look like;

```
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TimeString", type text}}),
    #"Add Hours" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Hours", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([TimeString], " ", " "), type text),
    #"Add Minutes" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Hours", "Minutes", each Text.BetweenDelimiters([TimeString], " ", " ", 2, 0), type text),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Add Minutes", "Percentage of Minutes in month ", each (1-(43800 - (Number.FromText([Hours]) * 60) - Number.FromText([Minutes] )) / 43800)*100)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```